# How to replace all '0xa0' chars with a ' ' in a bunch of text files?

Tags: python, bash, shell, text, utf-8

i've been trying to mass-edit a bunch of text files to utf-8 in python and this error keeps popping out. is there a way to replace them in some python scrips or bash commands?
i used the code:

```
writer = codecs.open(os.path.join(wrd, 'dict.en'), 'wtr', 'utf-8')
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(wrd,'*.txt')):
        print infile
        for line in open(infile):
                writer.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

and got these sorts of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dicting.py", line 30, in <module>
    writer.write(line2.encode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 216: unexpected code byte
```

Comment: Do you have any clue at all what is the encoding used in your input files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, first point: your output file is set to automatically encode text written to it as `utf-8`, so don't include an explicit `encode('utf-8')` method call when passing arguments to the `write()` method.

So the first thing to try is to simply use the following in your inner loop:

```
writer.write(line)
```

If that doesn't work, then the problem is almost certainly the fact that, as others have noted, you aren't decoding your *input* file properly.

Taking a wild guess and assuming that your input files are encoded in `cp1252`, you could try as a quick test the following in the inner loop:

```
for line in codecs.open(infile, 'r', 'cp1252'):
    writer.write(line)
```

Minor point: 'wtr' is a nonsensical mode string (as write access implies read access). Simplify it to either 'wt' or even just 'w'.

Comment: If the encoding of a file is said to be `latin1` or unknown, or there is no mention of such a concept, then surely the encoding is `cp1252`, unless of course the file is ancient, in which case the encoding is `cp850` or `cp437`, unless of course the file results from concatenating many others, in which case the encoding may well be a fubarred mixture.

Comment: The horrid thing about `latin1` is that `str.decode('latin1')` will never raise an exception complaining about an unmapped byte, and "doesn't raise an exception" is often conflated with "works" in this neck of the woods.

Comment: Good point, I changed the wild guess to `cp1252`. Unfortunately, the OP has already accepted the head in the sand "just ignore the errors that are trying to tell you something important" answer :P

Answer (score 3):

Did you omit some code there?  You're reading into `line` but trying to re-encode `line2`.

In any case, you're going to have to tell Python what encoding the input file is; if you don't know, then you'll have to open it raw and perform substitutions without help of a codec.

Comment: i was trying out line2 = line.replace('\xa0', ' ')